# Poisson distribution cost function

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Could I have some assistance with part b of the following question: 
Is it incorrect to substitute poisscdf(3,3) into the y component of the equation as 3 is the expected value of the distribution?

The number of machine failures per month in a certain plant has a Poisson distribution with mean equal to 3. Present facilities at the plant can repair 4 machines per month. If any additional machines fail then they are repaired by an outside contractor.

1. Use Matlab to find the probability, on a given month, that the contractor is required to work in the plant. Give your answer to three decimal places.
2. The cost (in thousands of dollars) to the plant of machine failures can be approximated as: 
   $$X = 17+5Y+Y^2 $$
   Find (to one decimal place) the expected cost of machine failures per month (in thousands of dollars).

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS**

Let $N$ be the number of failures in a particular month. Then, $N \sim \mathcal{P}(3)$. Do you know what are the expected value and variance of $N$?

1. Can you find $\mathbb{P}[N \ge 5] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[N < 5]$ and relate it to the desired quantity?
2. You are looking for $$\mathbb{E}\left[17 + 5N + N^2\right] = 17 + 5 \mathbb{E}[N] + \mathbb{E}\left[N^2\right].$$ You may want to remember that $$\mathrm{var} N = \mathbb{E}\left[N^2\right] - \mathbb{E}[N]^2...$$

Comment: That makes sense. Need to find N>=5 as they can only repair 4 machines. But I am confused about the expected value. Isn't the expected value for poisson distribution = lambda which in this case is 3?

Comment: @thehappyleaf Indeed, $\mathbb{E}[N] = \mathrm{var} N = 3$. What are you confised about?

Comment: Well, when I substitute this value into the function I get 41. The answer is 44.

Comment: @thehappyleaf it works just fine, I tried it, you get $44$. Just remember that $\mathbb{E}[N]^2 \ne \mathbb{E}\left[N^2\right]$...

Comment: oh i see. using the variance formula to find E[N^2]. I got the solution, thanks!!